# How can I download a TED transcript to a Kindle Paperwhite

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, download

How can I download a TED transcript to a Kindle Paperwhite so I am able to read the *entire* presentation, not just the introduction or synopsis (as I am seeing now)?

Answer (score 1):

There are some ease ways and some that might require programming skills.

I'm describing the easy way:

1. Install the [Send to Kindle extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/send-to-kindle-for-google/cgdjpilhipecahhcilnafpblkieebhea?hl=en) for Your browser (I'm using Chrome)
2. Configure it to Your needs
3. Visit the TED talk that has a transcription, [e.g. this one, and click on the transcript link under the video](https://www.ted.com/talks/mary_roach_10_things_you_didn_t_know_about_orgasm/transcript), choose Your language.
4. Now click on the "Send to Kindle" button on Your browsers toolbar to send it to Your Kindle
5. Turn on the wifi and sync Your Kindle.